# Allow users to disable notifications about their bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounties, notifications

I often add a bounty on a question, and having accounts on many sites, I can sometimes find myself with several bounties running simultaneously on different sites. The thing that annoys me the most about the current system are the constant notifications:

> [image]

- These notifications are useless if there's no answer for the bountied question, as there isn't anything I can do after getting notified
- Even if there's an answer, I've often seen it already and decided it doesn't deserve the bounty
- Knowing that the bounty runs out in X days is not important at all, especially when running several of them every week

It would be great if we had a button to disable all (or some) of the bounty notifications in user settings.